# calling property file and matching value in it with python script

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate the download file through Python selenium, where file name will be different every day.

I want to create a property file as like below, and read that file in Python script based on current date and download that file.

- 2019-04-10  abc1
- 2019-04-11  abc2
- 2019-04-12  abc3
- 2019-04-13  abc4
- 2019-04-14  abc5
- 2019-04-15  abc6

Please help me, how can I make it possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: what you try for solving this isssue? post your code...

Comment: Initially i tried to do it with if condition below, but i know it's not the proper way and want to move it property file. Am just a beginner to python, search a few pages but end with no luck. 
if cur_date == '2019-04-10':
 filename='abc1'
 print ("Current Date is:", cur_date, "Download Filename is:", filename)
elif cur_date == '2019-04-15':
 filename='abc2'
 print ("Current Date is:", cur_date, "Download Filename is:", filename)
else:
 print ("Unknown error...")

Comment: Have managed to read the property file and filter the required with below code

cur_date = datetime.date.today()
cur_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
for line in open(r'<path>\ConfigFile.properties'):
 if cur_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in line:
  print (line)
  filename=line.split("=",1)[1]
  
now i want to download the file with below code
browser.find_element_by_link_text('filename').click()

but it fails as unable to read the input file 'filename', if i input the string manually it works without any issue.